# How to insert taskId in to file table in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

in my laravel 5.2 application I have file attachment form and save information in file table.

files/form.blade.php

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form"
                                    enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                    method="post"
                                    action="{{ route('projects.files', ['projects' => $project->id]) }}">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('file_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="file" name="file_name" class="form-control" id="file_name">
                @if ($errors->has('file_name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('file_name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add Files</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        </form>
```

Filecontroller

```
public function uploadAttachments(Request $request, $id,$taskId)
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
            'file_name'     => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,pdf|between:1,7000',
        ]);

        $filename     = $request->file('file_name')->getRealPath();

        Cloudder::upload($filename, null);
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

        $fileUrl = Cloudder::show(Cloudder::getPublicId(), ["width" => $width, "height" => $height]);
        $this->saveUploads($request, $fileUrl, $id,$taskId);

        return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Your Attachment has been uploaded Successfully');
    }

    private function saveUploads(Request $request, $fileUrl, $id,$taskId)
    {
        $file = new File;
        $file->file_name  = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->file_url   = $fileUrl;
        $file->project_id = $id;
        $file->task_id = $taskId;
        $file->save();
    }
```

Now I have task form in show.blade.php in projects file in view folder projects/show.blade.php

```
<form  method="post" action="{{ route('projects.tasks.create', $project->id) }}">
 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Add Task" value="{{ old('name') ?: '' }}">
                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

    @endif
    <br>
    <div style='display:none'; class='somename'>

<div class="form-group">
        <textarea name='body'class="form-control">{{ old('body') }}</textarea>
    </div>

<div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
@include('files.form') //include File.form
```

This is my file table structure

```
id   file_name   file_url    project_id
```

When I open task data enter form I can see file enter form also, but now I need enter taskId to the file table with related to the each tasks. How can I do this?

Comment: no any idea here

Comment: need some help to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all your 'files/form.blade.php' file is making a POST and not GET, so you need to include a input for taskid like you did for file_name.
maybe:

```
<input type="hiden" value="ID" /> //ID 
<input type="hiden" value="taskID" /> //TASK ID
```

then in filecontroller > uploadAttachments() you need to get values from post.

```
$filename     = $request->file('file_name')->getRealPath();
$id = $request->input('id');
$taskID = $request->input('taskID');
```

After that you can call saveUploads(); for save.

..or if you post to route with parameters then include your taskID in form action.

```
{{ route('projects.files', ['projects' => $project->id, 'taskid' => 'IdHere']) }}
```